# How to make contact us form in android

Tags: android, email

I want to make a contact us form in android

how can I make a form that sends an email to me directly with the information the user entered

I don't want my app to switch to any mailing app , just sends the email to me when clicking the send button

In fact , I want to know what is the concept for this in general not necessarily for android
how can you send an email to me from the form without using your email?

Comment: @XaverKapeller Woohoo!

Comment: Yes I searched, and and Josef answered something else that I'm not asking for!

thank you for downvoting before understanding!

Comment: I found hundreds of tutorials , all about using users' emails "which I'm trying to avoid"

I'm asking about a concept in the first place , "How to send an email without email!" , I have no idea if that's even possible
if you know the answer and think it's really that simple then am sorry, but what I can see here someone trying to be smart ***

Comment: The difference is, when you go to cantact us page on any website, the website already have a server that can email its self, this doesn't apply in android or any other mobile application , I don't have a server to let php send me an email! I'm asking if that's even possible 

it seems to me you don't Understand what I'm talking about and you just like to seem smart downvoting others!

Answer (score 4):

The best (and easiest) way is to use an Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Otherwise you'll have to write your own client.

Also use .setType("message/rfc822") so it won't show you all of the apps that support the send intent.

Comment: thank you for your respond , but this is exactly what I don't want
this way you want to use another app to send the email

I don't wan't to use another app , like in any web page when you go to the contact us, you can send the email directly from the page without using your email

Answer (score -1):

This is an old QN, but for those that end up here I would recommend you build your own backend(API) and have an end point that receives the user's email details and then the backend proceeds to send the email to you for example if you develop the backend using PHP you can use a library like PHPMailer to do the emailing.